# Vector iterator -> Printing clases (missing argument)

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, polymorphism

I am using VS V++ 2013. I have function that takes vector as parametar and prints out classes(I got abstract class, and few childs). I've done everything except printing. I have problems with vector iterator. 
I am getting this error every time i try to compile
Here is my function:
**Error 1   error C3867: 'std::vector>::begin': function call missing argument list; use '&std::vector>::begin' to create a pointer to member**

```
void printList(const vector <Employee *> & Ve)
{   
    for (std::vector < Employee *>::iterator it = Ve.begin ;it != Ve.end(); ++it)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the parentheses:

```
for (std::vector < Employee *>::const_iterator it = Ve.begin() ;it != Ve.end(); ++it)
                                                            ~~
```

Another issue, you passed the `vector` as `const`, and call `begin()` on it will return a `const_iterator`. You should change the declaration of the iterator, or just use `auto` (from c++11):

```
for (auto it = Ve.begin() ;it != Ve.end(); ++it)
```

Comment: When i tried like that i got another error **Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Employee *>>>' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Employee *>>>' **

Comment: You might use `const_iterator`. See my edited answer.

Comment: I figured that out, but when i try to use my virtual function from my classes i cant use. It says
**IntelliSense: class "std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Employee *>>>" has no member "printPay"**

`it->printPay();`

Comment: @NikolaButigan Is `printPay` a non-const member function? The vector `Ve` is passed as const, non-const member function couldn't be called on it. Could you pass it without const? i.e. `void printList(vector <Employee *> & Ve)`

Comment: The loop is fine now(works both with `const_iterator` and with `auto` but i cant access my `printPay();` virtual function from classes.

Comment: @NikolaButigan Please show the code of `printPay()` 's declaration, and how you call it in the loop.

Comment: I have to use `void printList(const vector <Employee *> & Ve)`

Comment: This is from base abstract class `Employee` `virtual void printPay() = 0;` . And this is from one child class `virtual void printPay();` Declaration  `void HourlyEmployee::printPay(){ cout << "Employee ID: " << this->getEmpID() << " Weekly pay: $" << hours * payRate << endl; }`

Comment: @NikolaButigan Then could you declare `printPay()` as a const member function? Seems it doesn't modify anything of the class. i.e. `virtual void printPay() const = 0;`

Comment: Even when i add `const` in `printPay()` definition and declaration i still cant access to that function `for (auto it = Ve.begin(); it != Ve.end(); ++it)
 {
  it->printPay();
 }`

Comment: @NikolaButigan Try `(*it)->printPay();`.

Comment: I will find you, i will meet you i will buy you tons of beer. Thank you so much.

Comment: @NikolaButigan Glad to help. Note the type of vector's element is `Emplyee*`, i.e. a pointer, you just didn't call `printPay()` on it correctly.

Comment: Now i'm having a problem when i execute my pogram. I called functions,  and when it comes to printing it breaks. http://i.imgur.com/6klUtgJ.png

Comment: @NikolaButigan I guess because you new a pointer, and push_back it in the vector, and then delete it, and then loop the vector and call member function on the pointer, which has become a dangled pointer.

Comment: This is push back functions. `Employee*  temphourly = new HourlyEmployee(id, hours, payrate);
   Ve.push_back(temphourly);
   delete temphourly;  // preventing memeory leak`

Comment: @NikolaButigan Don't delete them until you don't use them no longer. If you want to avoid memory leak, you could use smart pointer, such as `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`, or don't use pointer at all. e.g. `std::vector<Employee>`.